# Is it possible to find explicit formula for the product $\prod_{\substack{d\mid n \\ d>1}} (1-\mu(d)/\varphi(d))^{\varphi(d)}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am trying to calculate the following product

$$
\prod_{\substack{d\mid n \\ d>1}} \left( 1-\frac{\mu(d)}{\varphi(d)} \right)^{\varphi(d)}
$$
where the functions $\varphi$ and $\mu$ are Euler's totient and  Mobius functions, respectively.
I am especially interested in finding explicit formula when $n$ is a square-free number. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me exactly what you want; you ask for an explicit formula, yet the function is already given to us by a fairly explicit formula. Do you want to know if there is a "simpler" formula? Your function is not multiplicative, so standard tricks to simplify it do not work here. Alternatively, would information about the growth rate/average order/Dirichlet series of your function suffice?

Comment: Yes, I am searching for a "simpler" form of the function for $n$ square-free and I doubt that this can be done. On the other hand, any other information concerning asymptotic behavior of the function is welcomed.

Comment: One thing you might note is that your product is $0$ if $n$ is even.

Comment: If for instance $n=pq$, then the product is $(\frac{p-2}{p-1})^{p-1} (\frac{q-2}{q-1})^{q-1} (\frac{pq-p-q+2}{(p-1)(q-1)})^{(p-1)(q-1)}$ which has no evident cancellation or further factorisation, and only a small amount of like terms to collect.  Doesn't seem like there is much else to be done here.

Comment: Asymptotics are more interesting; writing $(1 - \frac{\mu(d)}{\phi(d)})^{\phi(d)}$ as $\exp( \mu(d) - \frac{\mu(d)^2}{2\phi(d)} ) (1 + O(\frac{1}{\phi(d)^2} ))$, the product becomes $\exp( -\frac{1}{2} - \sum_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)^2}{2\phi(d)}) ( 1 + O( \sum_{d|n; d>1} \frac{1}{\phi(d)^2} ))$ which can simplify to $\exp(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\prod_{p|n} (1+\frac{1}{2(p-1)})) (1 + O( \sum_{p|n} \frac{1}{p^2} )))$.  One can be a bit more accurate about the contribution of the small primes $p$ to the error term if one wants more precise asymptotics.

Comment: In view of the recent edits and the fact that it’s a bit odd for $\varphi(d)$ to appear in an exponent, I wonder whether that’s not a typo for $\mu(d)$ or better yet, $\mu(n/d)$.

Comment: I think I made a number of sign errors in my previous comments and are no longer able to edit them to correct this, but the broad point of my comments are still valid even if the specific formulae should not be taken literally.